# R: Extracting proper time-date out of csv

Tags: r, csv, time-series, text-parsing

I have a csv with some time series data with date-time formatted like this:

```
mydata <- read.csv("mydata.csv")
> mode(mydata$t_5min[1])
[1] "numeric"
```

It looks like R is interpreting it as a factor, since it can't understand the format:

```
mydata$t_5min[1]
[1] 1/3/2012 16:00
27698 Levels: 10/10/2012 10:00 10/10/2012 10:05 10/10/2012 10:10 10/10/2012 10:15 ... 9/6/2012 9:55
```

I tried using strptime, which seems to work okay on single entries:

```
> strptime(x=mydata$t_5min[2],format="%d/%m/%Y %H:%M", tz="")
[1] "2012-04-01 06:10:00"
> mode(strptime(x=mydata$t_5min[2],format="%d/%m/%Y %H:%M", tz=""))
[1] "list"
```

But if I try this with sapply, I get the following error:

```
mydata$t_5min <- sapply(mydata$t_5min, strptime, format="%d/%m/%Y %H:%M", tz="")
Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, "t_5min", value = list(sec = 0, min = 0L,  : 
replacement has 9000 rows, data has 1000
```

I tried the timeDate library with slightly better results:

```
> as.timeDate(mydata$t_5min[1])
GMT
[1] [2012-01-03]
```

However, I need minute precision. However, the example code in the timeDate function doesn't seem to work (or I'm using it wrong, but it was kind of brief):

```
as.timeDate(mydata$t_5min[2], units=c("min"))
Error in as.timeDate(mydata$t_5min[2], units = c("min")) : 
unused argument(s) (units = c("min"))
```

**What's the right way to do convert this time data into something R can work with?**

Here is some data to duplicate these results:

```
t_5min,n,value
1/3/2012 16:00,16,48.125
1/3/2012 16:05,28,44.39285714
1/3/2012 16:10,29,37.44827586
1/3/2012 16:15,28,30.39285714
1/3/2012 16:20,28,23.67857143
1/3/2012 16:25,29,19.10344828
1/3/2012 16:30,28,16.35714286
1/3/2012 16:35,29,14.34482759
1/3/2012 16:40,28,11.71428571
```

Comment: `strptime` is vectorized. No need for an `*apply` function when using it on a data.frame column. Try `strptime(x=mydata$t_5min,format="%d/%m/%Y %H:%M", tz="")`

Comment: I also advice you to set the time zone explicitly (e.g., `tz="GMT"`) to avoid problems with daylight saving time.

Comment: Thanks, I've been wondering that exact thing about strptime!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

```
> as.POSIXlt(as.character(df$t_5min), format="%d/%m/%Y %H:%M")
[1] "2012-03-01 16:00:00" "2012-03-01 16:05:00" "2012-03-01 16:10:00"
[4] "2012-03-01 16:15:00" "2012-03-01 16:20:00" "2012-03-01 16:25:00"
[7] "2012-03-01 16:30:00" "2012-03-01 16:35:00" "2012-03-01 16:40:00"
```

Comment: This was easiest to adapt to my existing code, though I should definitely get around to learning zoo.

Comment: @TrevorAlexander Yep, you're right. I don't ue zoo for directly managing time series (yet) but it does have many useful functions to make life easier, like as.yearmon.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `read.zoo` to read directly your data in the right format:

```
library(zoo)
## you repalce text=... here by file = "mydata.csv"
read.zoo(text='
t_5min,n,value
1/3/2012 16:00,16,48.125
1/3/2012 16:05,28,44.39285714
1/3/2012 16:10,29,37.44827586
1/3/2012 16:15,28,30.39285714
1/3/2012 16:20,28,23.67857143
1/3/2012 16:25,29,19.10344828
1/3/2012 16:30,28,16.35714286
1/3/2012 16:35,29,14.34482759
1/3/2012 16:40,28,11.71428571',header=TRUE,format="%d/%m/%Y %H:%M", tz="",sep=',')


                    n    value
2012-03-01 16:00:00 16 48.12500
2012-03-01 16:05:00 28 44.39286
2012-03-01 16:10:00 29 37.44828
2012-03-01 16:15:00 28 30.39286
2012-03-01 16:20:00 28 23.67857
2012-03-01 16:25:00 29 19.10345
2012-03-01 16:30:00 28 16.35714
2012-03-01 16:35:00 29 14.34483
2012-03-01 16:40:00 28 11.71429
```